# Not Able to Parse multiple records in Libxml2

Tags: objective-c, libxml2

I have a collection of records which i am parsing using libxml2.

example:

```
<Customer><name>ABC</name><age>22</age></Customer> 
<Customer><name>XBF</name><age>23</age></Customer>
<Customer><name>AHG</name><age>22</age></Customer> 
<Customer><name>KKK</name><age>24</age></Customer>
<Customer><name>NNN</name><age>25</age></Customer>'
```

The problem is that on parsing i am able to parse the first record but the consecutive records are not parsed as the sax delegate startElementSAX() is not being called after parsing the first record.

Is there any way to call this SAX delegate function after the first record is parsed.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't know much about libxml2, but an XML file normally has a "root element", which is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Because they all got the same name. How to distinguish an element from another? You need to make it be an array:

```
<Customers>
    <Customer><name>ABC</name><age>22</age></Customer> 
    <Customer><name>XBF</name><age>23</age></Customer>
    <Customer><name>AHG</name><age>22</age></Customer> 
    <Customer><name>KKK</name><age>24</age></Customer>
    <Customer><name>NNN</name><age>25</age></Customer>
</Customers>
```

There is also an extra character at the end of the xml which I assume is a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having all of the elements named <Customer>, it's quite common.  You are correct that his real problem is having multiple root-level elements, and wrapping them in one outer element solves it.